# Why collections classes in C# (like ArrayList) inherit from multiple interfaces if one of these interfaces inherits from the remaining?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, arraylist

When I press f12 on the ArrayList keyword to go to metadata generated from vs2008, I found that the generated class declaration as follows

```
public class ArrayList : IList, ICollection, IEnumerable, ICloneable
```

I know that the IList already inherits from ICollection and IEnumerable, so why does ArrayList redundantly inherit from these interfaces?

Comment: +1 Thats a very good question.

Comment: I agree. In reflector ArrayList is defined as public class ArrayList : IList, ICollection, IEnumerable, ICloneable

Comment: I've done some research and added an answer with a code example

Comment: Why does it matter ? Does it not make things clearer by including each of the above mentioned interfaces ?

Comment: @mP- it doesn't really matter, but it is still an interesting question!

Comment: Presently, if `IFoo` has member function `Woozle`, and `IDeluxeFoo` inherits `IFoo`, a class which implements `IDeluxeFoo` can explicitly implement either `IDeluxeFoo.Woozle` or `IFoo.Woozle`; both definitions are synonymous.  If the CLR for class which implemented `IDeluxeFoo` did not explicitly specify that it implements `IFoo`, I don't know if the CLR would recognize an implementation of `IFoo.Woozle`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

OK, I've done some research. If you create the following hierarchy:

```
  public interface One
    {
        void DoIt();
    }

    public interface Two : One
    {
        void DoItMore();
    }

    public class Magic : Two
    { 
        public void DoItMore()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void DoIt()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

And compile it, then reference the DLL in a different solution, type Magic and Press F12, you will get the following:

```
 public class Magic : Two, One
    {
        public Magic();

        public void DoIt();
        public void DoItMore();
    }
```

You will see that the interface hierarchy is flattened, or the compiler is adding the interfaces in? If you use reflector you get the same results too.

Update: If you open the DLL in ILDASM, you will see it saying:

implements ...Two

implements ...One.

Comment: I guess because it is pretty handy to know that. Not everyone knows that IList inherits from ICollection and IEnumerable (or replace this sentance with another hierarchy).

Answer (score 2):

The extra interfaces are shown because they are implied by IList. If you implement IList, you must also implement ICollection and IEnumerable.

Comment: okay, this means it is generated from vs and it is not the real declaration of the ArrayList?

Comment: Yes. If you use Reflector to see the base types, you see it only explicitly implements IList and ICloneable. That's also the case in Microsoft's public Rotor source code: http://www.123aspx.com/Rotor/RotorSrc.aspx?rot=39810

Comment: I guess VS could be flattening the method implementation. That is to say, since IList implements ICollection, ArrayList is providing the implementation of ICollection methods.

Comment: but it is already in the documentation
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I am just guessing, but I think in reality it only implements IList in code, but the documentation shows the rest of the interfaces as well to make it explicit to the programmer using the class.

Comment: Even if it does explicitly implement all of them, explicitness of interfaces is good as you can then tell everything you need to implement just by looking at those interfaces, rather than digging through interfaces and their bases, etc.

Comment: I can see your point, but I'm skeptical as to whether or not this is  a good thing. I guess it can't hurt to to be a little redundant, but I couldn't ever see myself coding something this way, which still begs the question: where has MS documented their intentions for doing this?

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157(VS.80).aspx)....

> If a class implements two interfaces
>   that contain a member with the same
>   signature, then implementing that
>   member on the class will cause both
>   interfaces to use that member as their
>   implementation.
>
> Explicit implementation is also used
>   to resolve cases where two interfaces
>   each declare different members of the
>   same name such as a property and a
>   method:

Comment: My question is why ArrayList inherits from ICollection and IEnumerable as long as IList inherits from both???

Answer (score 0):

Don't accept this as answer.

I am repeating what workmad3 said above.

By implementing it in ArrayList, it becomes easy for one to know - which interfaces ArrayList implements rather that going up to IList to find that it implements ICollection & IEnumerable.

That avoids the need for going back & forth the inheritance chain.

EDIT: At the basic level, an interface implementing another interface cannot provide the implementation. The class derived (from IList) hence indirectly implements ICollection & IEnumerable as well. So, even if you write your own class implementing IList (and not add ICollection, IEnumerable in the declaration) - you will see that it will have to provide the implementation for ICollection & IEnumerable.

And workmad3's reasoning makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the CLR does not support an interface that inherits from another interface.

C# however does support this construct but has to 'flatten' the inheritance tree to be CLR compliant.

[Edit]

After taking advise from below quickly setup a VB.Net project:

```
Public Interface IOne
    Sub DoIt()
End Interface

Public Interface ITwo
    Inherits IOne
    Sub DoIt2()
End Interface

Public Class Class1
    Implements ITwo

    Public Sub DoIt() Implements IOne.DoIt
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Sub

    Public Sub DoIt2() Implements ITwo.DoIt2
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Compiling results in the following (C#):

```
public class Class1 : ITwo
{
    public Class1();
    public void DoIt();
    public void DoIt2();
}
```

This show that VB.Net does **NOT** flatten the interface hierarchy as opposed to C#. I have no clue as to why this would be.

Comment: -1: Rather than guessing three weeks later, why not try it in VB.NET and find out, before answering. Surely there was no hurry.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList is supposed to explicitly contain ICollection and IEnumerable implementations, just like the IList interface, which contains ICollection and IEnumerable implementations. But the ArrayList implementation should not be dependent on IList. In such a way that if the list structure changes, no effect will be felt on the ArrayList behavior. So they must be considered completely independent.
Inheriting ICollection and IEnumerable is important to ensure ArrayList independence. So if the IList structure changes and does not run ICollection or IEnumerable, the ArrayList structure will not change.

For example:
If you create the following hierarchy:

```
public interface IOne
{
   void DoIt();
}
public interface ITwo : IOne
{
   void DoItMore();
}
public class Magic : ITwo
{
    public void DoItMore()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public void DoIt()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Now interface ITwo decides not to use IOne implementation in its implementation. Since we explicitly inherited from IOne in the implementation of Magic, the program runs independently and does not depend on changes to the ITwo interface.

```
public interface IOne
{
   void DoIt();
}
public interface ITwo
{
   void DoItMore();
}
public class Magic : ITwo,IOne 
{
    public void DoItMore()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public void DoIt()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Update: If you look at the [.NET source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/arraylist.cs,43) and [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=net-6.0), you will see that the generated metadata is different from what you mentioned in the question.
This probably goes back to how IL emitted