# Why ArrayList implement IList, ICollection, IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, interface

`ArrayList` declares that it implements the `IList`, `ICollection`, and `IEnumeralbe` interfaces.

Why not only implement `IList`, because `IList` is also derived from `ICollection`, and `ICollection` is derived from `IEnumerable`.

What's the purpose of this kind of declaration? There are many cases like this in .NET BCL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the following code:

```
interface I1 { }
interface I2 : I1 { }

class Foo: I2 { }
```

If you look at Foo through reflection you will find

```
class Foo: I2, I1 { }
```

Which is also valid to compile and gives the same result.
So the difference is moot, and in documenting Foo you might as well write it with both interfaces.

Also see the SO question: [Why collections classes in C# (like ArrayList) inherit from multiple interfaces if one of these interfaces inherits from the remaining?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023375/why-collections-classes-in-c-like-arraylist-inherit-from-multiple-interfaces-i)

Answer (score 13):

There is no effective difference. I believe the extra declarations are there for clarity.

When checked in Reflector, classes which in code implement `IList` have the same interface declaration list as classes which in code declare implementing all of `Ilist`, `ICollection` and `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not so sure that `ArrayList` has separate implementations of the interfaces. Consider the following code:

```
public interface IBase
{
    int SomeInt { get; set; }
}

public interface ISub : IBase
{
    int SomeOther { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass : ISub
{
    public int SomeOther { get; set; }
    public int SomeInt { get; set; }
}
```

The `MyClass` type implements only the `ISub` interface directly. However, if you compile the code into an assembly, and then add that assembly as reference in another project, open the Object Browser and examine the base types for `MyClass`, it will feature something like this:

```
Base Types
 |- ISub
 |    |- IBase
 |- IBase
 |- Object
```

Answer (score -1):

1. IEnumerable - To support the foreach statement
2. ICollection - To support add single or multiple item in arraylist

Comment: questioner was not asking what they were for - was asking why they are explicitly listed as being implemented, when they are already implemented by virtue of inheritance on IList