# Why does Hashtable implement both ICollection and IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, .net, interface, hashtable

In .NET Framework 3.5 (C# 3.0) why does `System.Hashtable` implement both `ICollection` and `IEnumerable` when it already implements `IDictionary` that inherits these two interfaces?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/04/04/so-many-interfaces.aspx

Comment: That link answers everything related to my question. Thanks BlackBear.

Answer (score 2):

Having these intefaces:

```
interface IFoo1 {...}

interface IFoo2: IFoo1{...}
```

There is no difference in terms of compilation between followings:

```
class MyClass: IFoo2{...}

class MyClass: IFoo2, IFoo1{...}
```

The second declaration makes it clearer to developers all the interfaces MyClass class implements. So it is easier to have a look at the documentation and see that MyClass implements IFoo1 interface, without digging into IFoo2 interface.

Answer (score 0):

Since the direct base class of `Hashtable` is `System.Object` which implements no interfaces, *interface re-implementation* cannot be relevant here.

<strike>Since `IDictionary` does not hide any of the members it inherits from `IEnumerable` (for example it does not declare a `new` method `GetEnumerator()`), giving distinct implementation for members with the same names also cannot be the reason.</strike>

Since neither of the "usual" reasons applies, I have come to think that `Hashtable` implements both for no particular reason.

**Edit:**

Not sure this is even an answer.

Above statement was actually wrong. The non-generic `IDictionary` type ***does hide*** a member (overload) `GetEnumerator()` which it inherits from one of its base interface (non-generic) `IEnuemrable`. Not sure this is relevant, though. See the two implementations in `Hashtable` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb504489.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.getenumerator.aspx).

**New edit:**

Actually, if you check the source code (found e.g. [here](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/whidbey/REDBITS/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/Collections/Hashtable@cs/1/Hashtable@cs)), you see just:

```
public class Hashtable : IDictionary, ISerializable, IDeserializationCallback, ICloneable
```

But as written in [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1164840/1336654) in a thread already linked to by a comment by Henrik, in the compiled IL, all base interfaces are still listed explicitly. Hence decompilers that go from the IL in the compiled assembly to pseudo-C#, can't tell the difference.

---

**Final addition:**

I really tried to come up with a case involving *interface re-implementation* where it would matter if you gave also the base interface of an already specified derived interface, but I don't think any exists. This was my try:

```
interface IBase
{
    int Member { get; }
}
interface IDerived : IBase
{
}

class Animal : IBase
{
    int IBase.Member
    {
        get { return 10; }
    }
}
class Elephant : Animal, IDerived  // try ": Animal, IBase, IDerived"        ...        ...        ...        also try ": Animal, IBase"; try ": Animal"
{
    public int Member
    {
        get { return 20; }
    }
}

static class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        IBase elephantAsIBase = new Elephant();
        int readMember = elephantAsIBase.Member;
        Console.WriteLine(readMember);
    }
}
```

but turned out not to be an example. Even if only `IDerived` is specified for `Elephant`, all interfaces, including `IBase` are re-implemented. Only if `Elephant` specifies neither `IDerived` nor `IBase`, is re-implementation suppressed.

So Mert's answer and the linked answer are correct, and mine is somewhat off-topic. I'll leave this post for others to learn from, even if it is not strictly relevant to the question posed.