# Explicitly inherit 'grand parent' interface in inheritance list

Tags: c#, linq, inheritance, interface

I was having a look at the `IOrderedQueryable<T>` interface and noticed that it inherits from `IQueryable<T>` but also from `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>`, `IQueryable` and `IEnumerable`

```
public interface IOrderedQueryable<T> : 
    System.Linq.IQueryable<T>,
    System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>,
    System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable,
    System.Linq.IQueryable,
    System.Collections.IEnumerable
```

My question: Since `IQueryable<T>` already does inherit from these other interfaces why does `IOrderedQueryable` have to specify/inherit from these explicitly? Why not just inherit from `System.Linq.IQueryable<T>` and `System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable`.

Obviously this question is applicable to interface inheritance in general also.

Comment: Side note:Could not get the C# syntax to specify generics to appear correctly while typing.The angled brackets and T get eaten up.Hence used VB syntax.Any idea how I could get the C# syntax to work?

Comment: @alwayslearning: use &lt; and &gt; for angle brackets

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why collections classes in C# (like ArrayList) inherit from multiple interfaces if one of these interfaces inherits from the remaining?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023375/why-collections-classes-in-c-like-arraylist-inherit-from-multiple-interfaces-i)

Comment: When you 'format as code' (either inline with backquotes, or to a whole paragraph by indenting), your angle brackets survive. See my edit. Note that the 'format as code' button the editor will do the correct things, depending on what you have currently selected

Comment: @alwayslearning @henrik you can also just wrap them in tick marks: `. that automatically skips formatting.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817369/why-does-does-realy-list-implements-all-of-that-interfaces-not-just-ilistt) too, with a great accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classes automatically inherit these 'grand parent' interfaces, so you do not have to specify them explicitly. So, given these interfaces:

```
interface IBase {}
interface IChild: IBase {}
```

Either of these are fine:

```
interface IGrandChild: IChild {}
interface IGrandChild: IBase, IChild {}
```

The documentation just lists the ancestor interfaces [for convenience and clarity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817369/why-does-does-realy-list-implements-all-of-that-interfaces-not-just-ilistt/4818566#4818566): "It is much more clear for the documentation to be complete all in one place than to make you search through ten different pages to find out what the full interface set is."