# Why "public class ArrayList : IList, ICollection, IEnumerable, ICloneable", rather than "public class ArrayList : IList, ICloneable"?

Tags: c#

I find that in `System.Collections.ArrayList.cs`:

```
public class ArrayList : IList, ICollection, IEnumerable, ICloneable
```

But

```
public interface IList : ICollection, IEnumerable
```

and

```
public interface ICollection : IEnumerable
```

---

Why not

```
public class ArrayList : IList, ICloneable
```

and

```
public interface IList : ICollection
```

?

I'm so confused. Who can help me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023375/why-collections-classes-in-c-sharp-like-arraylist-inherit-from-multiple-interf?rq=1

Comment: [So many interfaces!](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/04/04/so-many-interfaces.aspx) In particular: "**Why does MSDN have the full interface list but the real source code does not?**

*Because MSDN is documentation; it's supposed to give you as much information as you might want. It is much more clear for the documentation to be complete all in one place than to make you search through ten different pages to find out what the full interface set is.*"